# Fit background image on div element with dynamic width

Tags: html, css, background-image

How to fit the div to 100% of it's container and maintain the same background image if we specified a background-position for that image?

**CSS**

```
#content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0 0 50% 0;
}
.icon-1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   background: url( "/path/to/my/image.png" ) no-repeat -50px -50px;
  /*
  -50px -50px is corresponding to letter "D" in the image
  */
 }
```

**The HTML**

```
<div id='content'>
   <div class='icon-1'>
   </div>
</div>
```

The idea is to use a single file for some icon-like images (to visually represent each shopping category)

```css
#content {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 50%;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0 0 50% 0;
}
.icon-1 {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%; 
   background: url( "https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FzW2.png" ) no-repeat -50px -50px #aa0000;
  /*
  -50px -50px is corresponding to letter "D" in the image
  */
 }
```

```html
<div id='content'>
   <div class='icon-1'>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: test image]

Comment: you mean you want the D to fit all the red block ?

Comment: Yes, that's I want. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to adjust the value of background. In your case, it should be 2x the size of the red box then adjust the position to bottom/right to have the `D` and top/left for the `A` and so on:

```css
#content {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  padding: 0 0 50% 0;
}

.icon-1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FzW2.png") bottom right/200% 200% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <div class='icon-1'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. I will put around 20 images in a sigle file and will play with percentage. Thanks